# Use a web server app with Traefik at a given path

Tags: traefik

I have a web server app (nginx, html, png...) in a docker container that I can't run correctly with Traefik without 404 files.

All the source files are here to reproduce the test :

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── www
    ├── img
    │   └── test.png
    └── index.html
```

`./www/index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello world<br>
  <br>
  <img src="img/test.png">
</body>
</html>
```

`./Dockerfile`

```
# BUILD: # docker build -t testwww .
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY www /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`docker-compose.yml` :

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:v2.4.8
    command:
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.mystripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/myapp"

  myapp:
    restart: always
    image: testwww
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapproute.rule=PathPrefix(`/myapp`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapproute.middlewares=mystripprefix"
```

When I start with `docker-compose up` the URL `http://localhost/myapp` serves the `index.html` file as expected but the img is 404 (requested at `http://localhost/img/test.png`). It is 200 OK at `http://localhost/myapp/img/test.png`.

I tried all I could with replacepath, addprefix, replacepathregex... without success.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your picture available at `http://localhost/img/croissant.png`, you should use:

```
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapproute.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)"
```

Comment: Sure it works but i want the app available at http://localhost/myapp because there will be http://localhost/myapp2 and more. (sorry about wrong image name, i edited from croissant.png to test.png but not important)

Comment: If you want to have both `http://localhost/myapp/index.html` and `http://localhost/img/croissant.png`, you can have:
`- "traefik.http.routers.myapproute.rule=PathPrefix(`/`) || PathPrefix(`/myapp`)"``